# How to change the values of a parameter in multiple files using python

Tags: python-2.7

I am a new user of Python. I got to learn a way of changing value of a parameter in a single file. The script:

```
#####test.py##########
from sys import argv
script,filename,sigma = argv
file_data = open(filename,'r')
txt = file_data.read()
txt=txt.replace('3.7',sigma)
file_data = open(filename,'w')
file_data.write(txt)
file_data.close()
```

It's run in command line with test.txt as

```
test.py test.txt 2.
```

3.7 is replaced by 2 in test.txt, as a result.

Now if I want to do the same for all the .txt files in the directory e.g.

```
test.py *.txt 2
```

what are the suggested modifications?

Your suggestions are highly appreciated.

Hafiz.

Comment: Did you mean `sigma = argv[2]`? To list all text files, you could use the glob module. `from glob import glob` and then `for filename in glob('path/to/directory/*.txt'):` .

Comment: Yes, sigma = argv[2]. Actually, I wanted to pass argument to the script while I run it. I tried to integrate what you'd suggested. It came out to be: 
    from sys import argv
    script,filename,sigma = argv
    from glob import glob
   for filename in glob('C:\PROJ\BNS\python-files\*.txt'):
    file_data = open(filename,'r')
    txt = file_data.read()
    txt=txt.replace('3.7',sigma)
    file_data = open(filename,'w')
    file_data.write(txt)
    file_data.close()     but when I run this like test.py *.txt 2, it shows syntax error. Please suggest.

Comment: Ok, it's working. I could figure it out. Thnx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

bash (or whatever your shell is) will expand the `*.txt` (to `test0.txt test1.txt ...` or whatever the `*.txt` files in your current directory are called) before passing it to your python script. your python script will therefore get many arguments (and not just 2 as you expect). print `sys.argv` to inspect.

you could solve that in bash itself with something like

```
for name in *.txt; do test.py ${name} 2; done
```

otherwise you would need to treat `sys.argv` differently in python and allow for more than 2 arguments.

Answer (score 0):

Importing glob solved that issue. But I've got some queries.

**Query 1:**

I'm rewriting my code as:

```
#####test.py##########
from sys import argv
script,filename,sigma = argv
file_data = open(filename,'r')
txt = file_data.read()
txt=txt.replace('3.7'|'3',sigma) #gives syntax error
file_data = open(filename,'w')
file_data.write(txt)
file_data.close()
```

I want to replace 3.7 or 3 by sigma. What will be the corrected code?

**Query 2:**

I'm rewriting it in the following manner:

```
#####test.py##########
from sys import argv
script,filename,sigma = argv
file_data = open(filename,'r')
txt = file_data.read()
txt=txt.replace('x="2"','x=sigma')
file_data = open(filename,'w')
file_data.write(txt)
file_data.close()
```

With

```
py test.py test.txt 3.
```

I get x=sigma, but I want to get x=3

What'd be the modification?

Regards,

Hafiz